# Alternative to .offsetWidth with Chrome to force reflow on element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to force a reflow to specific element and noticed the `.offsetWidth` isn't working with Chrome. It doesn't reflow. What is the best workaround for this with JS, please?

Update: the `getClientRects` doesn't force to reflow in chrome as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. [element.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) is jsut a getter.

Comment: trying to force an element to reflow

Comment: You don't have to do anything to update the layout in web. Just modify its style. What do you mean reflow? [Demo Update Width](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp)

Comment: Elfayer, google for reflow and repaint

Comment: I do need this.

Comment: kindly provide detailed explanation of your problem in question itself with some visuals or supporting code you have

Comment: @joyann Maybe you can give the links you refer to? Add some tags to your question? Because it seems that your question involves more than just javascript.

Comment: emm... the only tag I can add, is chrome

Comment: `.offsetWidth` does work on chrome. What are you doing? Can you show some code? Can you provide a reproduction link? ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/))

Comment: I can't. Chrome DOES NOT reflow an element with `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight` and `getClientRects`

Comment: Because it is not suppose to. It's just a getter on the size of an element. Why would it reflow?

Comment: Elfayer... Use google to understand what reflow and repaint is, please.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame no one understood this question. It's essential for dealing with bugs like this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718908. I'm giving up and just setting some known style property to a different value and changing it back.